# parallel_reduce on double returning incorrect result

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, tbb

I am trying to use Intel TBB parallel_reduce to obtain the sum of array elements consisting of doubles. However the result is different compared to OpenMP reduction implementation.

Here is the OpenMP one:

```
double dAverageTemp = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:dAverageTemp)
for (int i = 0; i < sCartesianSize; i++)
    dAverageTemp += pdTempCurr[i];
```

This code returns the correct value which is "317.277**493**"; however this TBB code:

```
double dAverageTemp = tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<double*>(pdTempCurr, pdTempCurr + sCartesianSize - 1),
                                        0.0,
                                        [](const tbb::blocked_range<double*> &r, double value) -> double {
                                            return std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), value);
                                        },
                                        std::plus<double>()
                                        );
```

insists that the result is "317.277**193**".

What am I missing here?

Comment: 1e-4 is pretty good for a lot of domains. Likely tbb and omp take advantage of different optimizations.

Comment: The sequence of addition is different depending on the level of parallelism.  In math addition is associative and commutative, but not so in floating point.  So you have to expect the sum to change based on the sequence of addition.  BTW, why do you believe the first answer is more "correct"?

Comment: Apparently I am not satisfied with the precision and asking if *I* did miss anything. @BrianCain

Comment: Without any parallelism the result is what the OpenMP currently gives. @JSF

Comment: Consider using arbitrary precision arithmetic as a reference.  See also http://www.phys.uconn.edu/~rozman/Courses/P2200_11F/downloads/sum-howto.pdf for a discussion on Compensated Summation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although all comments about the order of summations are perfectly correct, the simple truth here is you have a bug in your code. All `std::`, `thrust::` and `tbb::` algorithms or constructors abide to the same philosophy when it comes to define ranges, which is to indicate from first element to take to first element not to take, like in a `for ( auto it = v.begin(); it < v.end(); it++)`

Therefore, here, your code for `tbb::blocked_range` should go up to `pdTempCurr + sCartesianSize`, not to `pdTempCurr + sCartesianSize - 1`.

It should become:

```
double dAverageTemp = tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<double*>(pdTempCurr, pdTempCurr + sCartesianSize ),
                    0.0,
                    [](const tbb::blocked_range<double*> &r, double value) -> double {
                         return std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end() value);
                    },
                    std::plus<double>()
              );
```

My (wild) guess is that `pdTempCurr[sCartesianSize-1]` is around `0.0003` which will account for the numerical difference experienced.